# Getting value of latest date column from a selection of tables in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

Say I have a view, called `vProducts`

`vProducts` selects data from `tblProducts, tblCategories, tblProductPrices`

Each of these 3 tables has a column called `dateUpdated` of type `DateTime`.

In my view, I'd like to have a column, also called `dateUpdated`

This should be whichever is the latest from `dateUpdated` in `tblProducts`, `tblCategories` or `tblProductPrices`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always just use a `CASE` statement to determine which of the three dates is the most recent one:

```
CREATE VIEW vProducts AS
   SELECT
      (your list of columns here....),      
      DateUpdated = 
        CASE    
          WHEN p.DateUpdated >= c.DateUpdated AND p.DateUpdated >= pr.DateUpdated
            THEN p.DateUpdated
          WHEN c.DateUpdated >= p.DateUpdated AND c.DateUpdated >= pr.DateUpdated
            THEN c.DateUpdated
          WHEN pr.DateUpdated >= c.DateUpdated AND pr.DateUpdated >= p.DateUpdated
            THEN pr.DateUpdated
          ELSE
            '19000101'
        END

    FROM 
        dbo.tblProducts p
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.tblCategories c ON .......
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.tblProductPrices pr ON .........
```

One of the three conditions should always apply (otherwise you'll get `19000101` as the value)

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION` to get all the dates from the three tables, then `ORDER` them:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT dateUpdated FROM tblProducts
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT dateUpdated FROM tblCategories 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateUpdated FROM tblProductPrices
)
SELECT dateUpdated FROM cte 
ORDER BY dateUpdated DESC
```